# Easy pie chart directive angulars

Tags: angularjs, pie-chart, angularjs-ng-repeat, directive

I'm trying to "integrate" a jQuery plugin called "[easy pie chart](http://rendro.github.io/easy-pie-chart/)", but I'm having some problems to do it, have you ever did something like this:

Basically, I'm trying to make a directive from this plugin. I did a couple of tests, but is not working yet.

Here I list the variations I tried:

- Create the chart on the jquery ready event equivalent,outside from ng-repeat. **This worked**
- Create the chart on the jquery ready event equivalent,inside the ng-repeat. **This worked**
- Translate the plugin to directive, inside the ng-repeat **Did not work**
- Translate the plugin to directive, outside the ng-repeat **Did not work**

[Plunkr with the mentioned variations](http://plnkr.co/edit/KOQ824pf7gjBzyzhIqOf?p=preview)

Comment: what have you tryed so far?
Here on SO we help people figure how what is wrong with their code. We don't do work for them

Comment: I thought it was explicit enough post a plunkr with WIP. Anyways, I'm creating a piechart directive with a library "easypiechart",I made some experiments like:
- Create the chart on the jquery ready event equivalent,outside from ng-repeat
- Create the chart on the jquery ready event equivalent,inside the ng-repeat
- Translate the plugin to directive, inside the ng-repeat
- Translate the plugin to directive, outside the ng-repeat
This could be a nice directive for all the comunity, specially for the begginers.
The code is in the plunkr, if you like to help me/us it would be so much appreciated!

Comment: It would help to describe what problems you are having

Comment: @JamesKleeh I just updated the description, hopefully is more descriptive :-P

Answer (score 6):

Version 2.0.0 includes an angular directive. You need a ng-controller with a percent object for each easy pie chart instance. Configre the options via the easypiechart-attribute in CSS inline-style notation. The demo/angular.html contained in the repository shows how to glue a range slider and a pie chart instance together.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**
In Version 2.0.4 which was released on Oct 10th, 2013 you can instantiate multiple charts on one controller. The angluar demo in the repo shows how it's done.